# Binding overloaded function

Tags: c++, boost

This code was developed and originally worked with boost 1.48. Since updating to boost 1.52 it refuses to compile.

```
boost::signals2::signal<void (uint32_t)> foo;
boost::shared_ptr<boost::circular_buffer<uint32_t>> _foo_buffer = new boost::circular_buffer<uint32_t>(32);
_foo.connect(boost::bind(&boost::circular_buffer<uint32_t>::push_front, _foo_buffer, _1));
```

The goal is to have `foo(42)` place `42` on the front of the circular buffer.

My compile error is `No matching function for call to 'bind'` with a bunch of `Candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'R'` and similar template errors.

I suspect the problem is that between the boost versions I'm using, the definition for push_front changed from

```
void push_front(const_reference item = value_type());
```

to the three definitions

```
void push_front(param_value_type);
void push_front(rvalue_type);
void push_front();
```

and it's confused my compiler.

I would really appreciate some help with the syntax of a connect expression that will work with the new boost library. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

let's say you have the two functions

```
void foo( int ) {}
void foo( double* ) {}
```

then you can't just write `&foo` since that would be ambiguous.

but you can use `static_cast` to establish a context where only one candidate is possible, thusly:

```
static_cast<void(*)(int)>( &foo )
```

which gives you the address of the first one, and ditto for the second one.

---

that said, it looks like you can simplify things by using a C++ lambda function instead of a `bind` (for a C++03 compiler alternatively define your own functot).

Comment: The static cast method didn't work for me, however it might have been a syntax error. `static_cast<void(boost::circular_buffer<uint32_t>::*)(uint32_t)>( &boost::circular_buffer<uint32_t>::push_front )` just spawned similar errors to the original. I'm not at my computer currently so I can't quote them.

However, C++ lambdas worked perfectly for me so it isn't an issue anymore. Thanks.